# Use singleton classes with cluster module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-cluster

I want to use [cluster module](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/cluster.html) in my node application. I am also using Prometheus in my application.

In the documentation, I read that with the cluster module a new process is spawned. Will it also create a new instance of cached node modules? Basically, I want to use the same registry of Prometheus so the scraper can get the data across all processes.

If a new object of the module(node module) will be created for the child process, how can I aggregate the metrics across all the processes and scrape that aggregated metric?

Comment: For each cluster worker a separate node.js process is spawned and has its own heap memory and therefore a new object instance is created.

Comment: So in this case, when prom scrapes it will get metrics from one process only, and not whole metrics, right?

Comment: Dont know, never worked with Prometheus. But thats how it is when you use the cluster module. Why dont you try it out with a simple test? Create a simple demo app with fake data. Why do you think you need a singleton instance?